# Issue running Python script in PowerShell - 'import' not recognized

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to run a Python script in PowerShell, but I'm encountering an issue. When I use the import pandas statement, PowerShell throws an error, saying "'import' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program." How can I resolve this and successfully run my Python script in PowerShell?

Answer (score 1):

From what you've written, I guess you're trying to run the import statement directly in powershell. This won't work.
Make sure you've written a python script first with your import statements and the code. The script can then be started using `python scriptname.py`

If you intend to "play" with python first, you can usually start an interactive mode by just typing `python` in powershell.

Answer (score 0):

The shell is interpreting the script rather than Python. It's PowerShell that doesn't know "import". Please try to
> python yourScript.py